# Play random sound

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js, fs

I'm making a discord bot and if I type $join into chat, I want the bot to join the voice channel that I'm in, and play a random sound.

```
case"join":
            message.delete( {timeout: 5000})
            const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel

            if(voiceChannel) {
                const connection = await voiceChannel.join()
                const soundFile = fs.readFileSync("./sounds/")
                const randFiles = soundFile[Math.floor(Math.random() * randFiles.length)]
                const dispatcher = connection.play(randFiles)
            } else {
                message.reply("you need to be in a voice channel!").then(message => message.delete( {timeout: 5000}))
            }
            break;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
(node:13932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:524:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:349:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:386:19)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\doge_bot\doge-bot.js:124:38)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:13932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13932) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not
handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation for `readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)? The only OS that `readFileSync()` successfully returns data on a directory path is on FreeBSD.

Instead, what it appears you're trying to do is grab a list of the files at a directory path; for this you could use [`fs.readdirSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options):

```
const soundFile = fs.readdirSync("./sounds/")
```

Comment: Thank you for help, that seems to be fixed, but now when I type $join, it joins to my voice channel and doesn't play anything.

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readFileSync("./sounds/")` is for reading the contents of a file.
You're probably looking for `fs.readdirSync("./sounds/")` which gives you an array of files in a directory.